# Btrieve Date Integer

Tags: date, pervasive, btrieve

this is my question:

I'm migrating data from a Btrieve file (.dat) through Pervasive Control Center and there is field type which is defined as integer but is a date and for example the date '31/12/2009' (seen in the legacy system) is view it as the number 733772 when I export it.

The legacy system shows the date correctly but I can't export it in the same format or at least I can't convert it. Does anybody know how to convert this number through Excel or something?

Comment: How are your reading .dat files, using btrcall function? I wanted to know, How did you get each field value?

Comment: I used "Pervasive Control Center" and it showed me the dat files, I even used sql commands on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I divided 733772 by 365.2425 (Number of days in year considering Leap year and 29 days of Feb - http://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html), it gave back 2009.

Comment: Do you have more data for date and number pairs?

Comment: Yes, 733741 is 30/11/2009 and 733711 is 31/10/2009.

Comment: Subtract 693594 from Whatever number you have derived from Btrieve file. Change format of output to Date category. It worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to format cells and changing category to date.