# C# .net Datetime to Integer value

Tags: c#, datetime

I am really new to C# and I am having problem in converting DateTime to it's Integer date format. I have search already the net but I did not find my answer.

I want is to convert the current Date to integer.
Example the date "2011-08-11" in format "yyyy-MM-dd" has an integer value of 734360

Comment: can you explain the relation between "2011-08-11" and 734360? I don't get it.

Comment: I'm not sure how you get from `2011-08-11` to `734360`?

Comment: Is this your custom convertion algorith r what?

Comment: @all, it is the date format use in pervasive sql, im really new to this type of format.

Comment: @rechie: Why are you storing `DateTime` in SQL as `integer`?

Comment: @neil: because i have no choice sir, the current database structure they have now is still using the legacy date format.

Comment: @all an oposite problem of mine is here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009057/btrieve-date-integer i am just giving you this link just to make some reference that this type of date format exist.

Comment: If OP know the relation, he will not need to ask this question.

Comment: I think the down-votes are a bit harsh, he's obviously a bit of a newbie and it's not that hard to work out anyway.

Comment: JobB its just ok if i get down-votes. It quite an harassment, but its find. thank you JonB for you answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pervasive uses days since 1/1/1.

To convert from int to a date use

```
new DateTime(1, 1, 1).AddDays(734360)
```

To convert to an int from a date use

```
TimeSpan t = (new DateTime(2011, 08, 11)-new DateTime(1, 1, 1));
int days = (int)t.TotalDays+1;
```

Comment: Be careful, when converting from the int format to the DateTime, don't forget to substract one to the number of days added (as 1/1/1 is the 1st day and not the 0th day).

Comment: @JobB yes your right Pervasive uses days since 1/1/1 that what my officemate told me.  thank you so much! that solves the my problem.

Answer (score 14):

`myDateTime.Ticks` will give you a uniquely representative `Int64` value if that is what you need.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this too:

```
DateTime MyDate = new DateTime(); 

int Year = MyDate.Year;
int Month = MyDate.Month;
int Day = MyDate.Day;
```

if it is what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
int calculation;
DateTime processDate;
calculation = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(processDate));
```

u can also use this way.